Inter-constellation Low Earth Orbit (LEO) Satellite collision risks - mitigation is some "relayed AIS" in use?
I saw some news about Starlink satellites often having the do maneuvers to avoid collisions. I don't know what % of the maneuvers were related to collisions between 2 Starlink ones (I guess their share of LEO satellites is pretty big).
My question is about how we mitigate/reduce risks of collisions between different constellations / "fleets":
At sea we use AIS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_identification_system) and rules "road" to reduce the risk.

(AIS transponders send the GPS data from ships to land station(s)
Navigation rules ("rules of road") define which vessel takes action to avoid collision when needed

In LEO, is there:
i. A centralized place where all the ground stations of (those satellites that have the capability), send their data
ii. Rules of who has the "orbit priority" and who has to change orbit to avoid the collision?

I guess (at least a couple yars ago) the answer to the question of the "rules of road" was that "we play chicken". See https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59710/how-do-satellite-operators-negotiate-when-a-collision-avoidance-measure-is-neces (I suppose e.g. the Starlink ones obviously avoid collisions between themselves). I just wish there are some "anti-chicken-game" efforts incl. some "AIS"-like system that would track the data.
